# Is there a way to return multiple data results into one cell?

Tags: excel, vba, autocad

I am building a code to retrieve all the text from multiple documents and then place the file name of that document in column A and then all the text contained in that document in the same row, but in column B. Right now, I have the code to where I can retrieve the text from these documents, but my problem is that I can't combine all the text entries into one cell. Each document contains a different number of text entries, so the code will have to contain all the text into one cell.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    Dim ent As AXDBLib.AcadEntity
    Dim txt As AcadText

Dim mtxt As AcadMText

Dim textValue As String

                      For Each ent In ActiveDocument.ModelSpace

                            If TypeOf ent Is AcadText Then

                                Set txt = ent
                                
                                Cells(4, 2) = txt.TextString
                                Debug.Print txt.TextString

                            End If
```

Comment: combine the returns with Chr$(10) then write to single cell?

Comment: excel can only hold 32,767 characters in each cell, this may be a problem if you are trying to place whole documents into a single cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub testAllInACell()
 'your existing code...
    For Each ent In ActiveDocument.ModelSpace
            If TypeOf ent Is AcadText Then
                Set txt = ent
                 If textvalue = "" Then
                    textvalue = txt.TextString
                 Else
                    textvalue = textvalue & vbLf & txt.TextString
                 End If
            End If
    Next
    If Len(textvalue) <= 32767 Then
            Cell(4, 2).value = textvalue
    Else
            MsgBox "The text to be copied exceeds the maximum allowed... " & vbCrLf & _
                   "(" & Len(textvalue) & " against 32767, admitted)"
    End If
    'Your existing code (if any...)
End Sub
```

Comment: hey that worked! Can I ask what this line means: If textvalue = "" Then.....sorry new to vba

Comment: @RawrRawr7 This means that the variable is empty/nothing. The code checks if it is empty and first time gives it the value of `txt.TextString`. Then, it concatenase the previous value with the next one, but separated by `vbLf` (line feed), which pass the second `txt` string on the following line.